# Gradients returning None in huggingface module

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I want to get the gradient of an embedding layer from a pytorch/huggingface model. Here's a minimal working example:

```
from transformers import pipeline

nlp = pipeline("zero-shot-classification", model="facebook/bart-large-mnli")

responses = ["I'm having a great day!!"]
hypothesis_template = 'This person feels {}'
candidate_labels = ['happy', 'sad']
nlp(responses, candidate_labels, hypothesis_template=hypothesis_template)
```

I can extract the logits just fine,

```
inputs = nlp._parse_and_tokenize(responses, candidate_labels, hypothesis_template)
predictions = nlp.model(**inputs, return_dict=True, output_hidden_states=True)
predictions['logits']
```

and the model returns a layer I'm interested in. I tried to retain the gradient and backprop with respect to a single logit I'm interested in:

```py
layer = predictions['encoder_hidden_states'][0]
layer.retain_grad()
predictions['logits'][0][2].backward(retain_graph=True)
```

However, `layer.grad == None` no matter what I try. The other named parameters of the model have their gradients computed, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. How do I get the grad of the encoder_hidden_states?

Comment: Can you check if embedding layer trainable?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov I'm not sure how to do that, I did check if `layer.requires_grad==True` but this is something else?

Comment: Keras layers have `trainable` attribute. I believe something similar should exist for tf/pytorch

Comment: Not sure if I am misunderstand your question, but `predictions['encoder_hidden_states'][0]` is not a layer. It is the output of a layer.

Comment: @cronoik it's perhaps my misunderstanding. I want the gradient of the input w.r.t. one of the final logits. Ideally, this would be right after it is one hot encoded if that makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was also very surprised of this issue. Although I have never used the library I went down and did some debugging and found out that the issue is coming from the library transformers. The problem is comming from from this [line](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/1073a2bde5d608f9891d6da6df7b63921dca1b71/src/transformers/modeling_bart.py#L382) :

```
encoder_states = tuple(hidden_state.transpose(0, 1) for hidden_state in encoder_states)
```

If you comment it out, you will get the gradient just with some dimensions transposed.
This issue is related to the fact that Pytorch Autograd does not do very well on inplace operations as mentioned [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/encounter-the-runtimeerror-one-of-the-variables-needed-for-gradient-computation-has-been-modified-by-an-inplace-operation/836/5).

So to recap the solution is to comment line 382 in *`modeling_bart.py`*.

You will get the gradient with this shape T x B x C instead of  B x T x C, but you can reshape it as you want later.

Comment: That's it! I'm very impressed that you found it and provided a reason to why it's failed. I'm going to bring this to the huggingface forum, I think it might be nice to have this without a crazy monkey patch.

Comment: Yeah totally, it should be an ‘easy’ fix I think.

Comment: This does appear to be the line causing the issue, but it isn't an in-place operation so I'm not sure the explanation makes sense. Maybe a PyTorch issue?

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue, and commenting out this line does not solve the issue. More particularly, I would like to get the gradients in the RoBERTa model, which does not transpose the hidden states and ``layer.grad`` is still None. Do I miss something in the example code (in the question) to get the gradients? my transformers version is 4.3.2. thanks!